# PHP: Is it possible to reuse MySQL pdo objects?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am allowing users to vote on content, so I need to save a user input to my database, and then get a `COUNT()` of the input to return back.

The voting works fine, but reading the results back always returns false. The only work around I have found is to rebuild the database connection a second time to count the votes. Is there any other way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
$vote = $conn->prepare($voteSQL);
$vote->execute(array(':postId'=>$voteId 
                     , ':voterId'=>$userId
                     , ':voteType'=> $voteDir
                     ,':voteType2'=> $voteDir
                     ,':voteType3'=> $voteDir));
$tallyVotes = $conn->prepare($tallySQL);
$tallyVotes->execute(array(':postId'=>$voteId));
$updatedTally = $tallyVotes->fetch();
```

Comment: check if you have transactions enabled by chance.

Comment: I am not explicitly using ::beginTransaction... how else would I check for this?

Comment: I'll admit, I'm having trouble following your question but by any chance are you trying to use PDO's `rowCount()` function?  If so, there are problems with it detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/count-with-pdo

Comment: does the db get updated immediately after the vote->execute is called ? ( like if you exit the application right after and you look at the data using a mysql client )