# select count(*) from table of mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am able to get both the value and row of the mysql query result.

But I am struggling to get the single output of a query. e.g.:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students;");
```

I need the result to display. But I am not getting the result.

I have tried with the following methods:

1. `mysql_fetch_assoc()`
2. `mysql_free_result()`
3. `mysql_fetch_row()`

But I didn't succeed to display (get) the actual value.

Comment: By now you should be using [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/883365/1505348).

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You need to alias the aggregate using the `as` keyword in order to call it from `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from Students");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Comment: After 5.x version this query will not work just replace mysql with mysqli to make it work.

Answer (score 33):

If you only need the value:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from Students;");
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: `echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from Students;"),0);` is saving one unnecessary variable

Comment: Correct; my answer was tailored to the question.

Comment: @eichertc the php interpreter has the variable always internal, as he needs to have the result in memory one way or the other.

So your way just makes the code worser to read and maintain, IMHO.

Answer (score 17):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `Students`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['count'];
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 14):

Please start using PDO.

mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed entirely in 7. Let's make it easier to upgrade and start using it now.

```
$dbh = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT count(*) as total from Students');
$sth->execute();
print_r($sth->fetchColumn());
```

Answer (score 9):

here is the code for showing no of rows in the table with PHP

```
$sql="select count(*) as total from student_table";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Comment: I like the use of `AS` here, instead of needing to type `echo $data['count(*)'];`

Answer (score 7):

```
$num_result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total_count from Students ") or exit(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($num_result);
echo $row->total_count;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can as well use this and upgrade to `mysqli_` (stop using `mysql_*` extension...)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `Students`");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $row['count'];
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 3):

With mysql v5.7.20, here is how I was able to get the row count from a table using PHP v7.0.22:

```
$query = "select count(*) from bigtable";
$qresult = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresult);
$count = $row["count(*)"];
echo $count;
```

The third line will return a structure that looks like this:

```
array(1) {
   ["count(*)"]=>string(4) "1570"
}
```

In which case the ending echo statement will return:

```
1570
```

Answer (score 3):

For mysqli users, the code will look like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Students_count FROM Students")->fetch_array();
var_dump($result['Students_count']);
```

or:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students")->fetch_array();
var_dump($result[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$db  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=java_db', 'root', 'pass');
$Sql = "SELECT count(*) as `total` FROM users";
$stmt = $db->query($Sql);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print '<pre>';
print_r($total);
print '</pre>';
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What's the need for line 5 ?   The compiler/IDE should warn about unused '$data' variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the aggregate using the `as` keyword in order to call it from `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) as total from Students");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $howmanyuser_query=$conn->query('SELECT COUNT(uno)  FROM userentry;');
 $howmanyuser=$howmanyuser_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); 
 echo $howmanyuser[0];
```

after the so many hours excellent :)