# Joining two tables to get a count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am attempting to count comments on a particular page with the following problematic sql query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE is_approved = '1' AND page_id = '943'"
$query = mysql_query($query);
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $total;
```

the problem is it is outputting 0 and not 2.

The tables are as follows:

pages:

```
id:1 page_id:943

id:2 page_id:978

id:3 page_id:977
```

comments:

```
id:2 page_id:1 "hello"

id:3 page_id:1 "great"

id:4 page_id:3 "super"
```

So really the original query should be getting each comment's **true** `page_id` from the `page_id` as set in the pages tables, as joined by `comments.page_id = pages.id`

What would the final code look like to either make that join, and/or get that count? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see is_approved field on your comments table..

Comment: anyway you need to join those table by Pages.id and Comments.pages_id

Comment: @Elior thats not true, you can use an `WHERE .. IN` statement

Comment: @joelharkes but it's more readable and faster with JOIN !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.* FROM `comments` c
JOIN `pages` p on c.page_id = p.id
WHERE c.is_approved = '1' AND p.page_id = '943'
```

Comment: In MySQL, a join will typically be faster than the equivalent correlated subquery.

Comment: Mark, would one get the same result using a SELECT count(*) rather than SELECT c.* ... maybe one can then skip a step?

Comment: @Adrian33: I would think so - I left it as `c.*` because I thought you wanted to use the values from the comments table (rather than just counting them).

Comment: right, someone does that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907751/select-count-from-table-of-mysql-in-php Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT * FROM comments, pages WHERE comments.page_id = pages.id AND is_approved = '1' AND comments.page_id = '943'"
```

Comment: Should probably be `pages.page_id='943'`.

Comment: note that this can also be done by an `WHERE .. IN` statement

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM `comments` c join pages p on c.page_id =  p.id
WHERE c.is_approved = '1' AND p.page_id = '943'
```

It seems like a very poor database design to have two columns with the same name in different tables that mean different things.  You should probably change the name of `pages.page_id` to something else.

And, this returns the count directly, so you can read the value from the row.  If you just want the count, there is no reason to return all the matching rows.

Comment: thx Gordon. If reading straight from query, then $query=mysql_query($query); becomes $total=mysql_query($query); - also should "join pages p" be "join \`pages\` p" -- with the quotes on pages?

Comment: @Adrian33 . . . No, you need to add a reader to get the value returned by the query when you run it.

Comment: this query is working, you wouldn't mind being able to provide the reader to get it into a variable, (excuse my challenges right now.)

Answer (score 0):

no join is needed:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE is_approved = '1' AND WHERE page_id IN (SELECT id WHERE page_id = '943')"
$query = mysql_query($query);
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $total;
```

ofcourse i would suggest a count statement if you do not need/use the data:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `comments` WHERE is_approved = '1' AND WHERE page_id IN (SELECT id WHERE page_id = '943')"
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$total = $row['total'];
echo $total;
```

Comment: thx. I'm getting " mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in" for line 3.