# PHP count forum posts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get count of posts
in "posts" table,

```
i have id,topic_id (topic_id= the topic id)
```

in "topics" table,

```
i have id,f_id (f_id= the forum id )
```

i try while and while, but not wor
how can i count the posts?
for ex:

```
<php?
$test2=mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(topic_id) AS post_count FROM posts t LEFT JOIN topics p ON p.id = t.id WHERE `f_id`='1' GROUP BY t.id") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907751/select-count-from-table-of-mysql-in-php

Comment: just a query with count and group by `SELECT t.* ,COUNT(*) FROM topics t JOIN posts p ON(p.f_id=t.id) GROUP BY t.id`

Comment: i need to do like this: count ,where id=topic_id and topic_id=id and id=forum_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(topic_id) AS post_count 
FROM posts t 
LEFT JOIN topics p 
ON p.id = t.id AND `f_id`='1' 
GROUP BY t.id
```