# How can i print how many Id's i have in my database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why this isn't working and i don't know how to fix it:

```
    $sum=0;
    $queryone="SELECT SUM(ID) FROM seriestwo";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$queryone);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $sum = $sum + 1;

    }
echo $sum
```

it always prints 0.

Comment: You're using the wrong logic. You're doing `while($row...` but not doing anything "with" `$row`. You should also be counting not summing, unless that's what you want, I don't know.

Comment: i updated it, i am summing, i want to show how many entries there are in the database, for example id 1 id 2 id 3 it willl print 3 ids

Comment: I noticed the other answer made an edit to their answer using an alias where I did not see it when I posted my own answer. You have a choice now.

Comment: Ok, I noticed you accepted their answer. I'm glad you got your solution then. I was away for a bit, which explains my late answer. "Hunger" got the best of me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong because the `$result` stores only 1 row, that is the sum of ID. You can try two things:

**Method 1**: Use `COUNT()` in mysqli. Check [MySQL Reference](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMloLm5OTOAhVLQo8KHZ4EBFwQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Fmysql%2Fen%2Fcounting-rows.html&usg=AFQjCNEWYmZU1eMqiypBPZkp5lVOms29KQ&sig2=8qnXjGMMPateYIV6o10KQQ)

For eg. check: [select count(*) from table of mysql in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907751/select-count-from-table-of-mysql-in-php)

```
$queryone="SELECT COUNT(ID) as total FROM seriestwo";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$queryone);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row['total'];
```

**Method 2:** Use this code:

```
$sum=0;
$queryone="SELECT `ID` FROM seriestwo";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$queryone);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $sum = $sum + 1;
}
echo $sum;
```

**Which Method to Use**

The first method is the one you should be using right now, in this case. You can use second when you want to add extra things, like print every ID

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking this.

It's as simple as the following and using an alias while using only 3 lines of code:

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT SUM(`ID`) as `total` FROM seriestwo");
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['total'];
```

Comment: Though your approach is right, I think the user wants to count the number of ids and not the sum. I am not sure but.

Comment: @DarshanJain TBH, after seeing their comment about *"for example id 1 id 2 id 3 it willl print 3 ids"* in comments above, had second thoughts in regards to the answer I gave here, where I should have used a different approach. Don't get me wrong, I don't want to take away from your answer. They also wrote *"i updated it, i am summing"*.