# Return Count From Database Into PHP As Variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to get a count of how many entries are in a database by using COUNT in SQL similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907751/select-count-from-table-of-mysql-in-php). This is my code, it returns/echos nothing.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM Customer");

if (!$result) echo mysql_error();

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['total'];

$id=$row['total'];

echo($id);
```

What is wrong? The connection info is correct and has no errors.

Update: I still need help with this. Please stop downvoting and not giving answers. If it's a question with an obvious answer please tell me.

Update: This is not at all a duplicate of that question. The issue was not specifically with error reporting.

Update: I answered this question and figured out my problem was with the default database which is why nothing was being returned. I can't select my answer until tomorrow.

Comment: Try echo ```"<p>Row<pre>".print_r($row,true)."</pre></p>"``` to see the result set. That may clear up how to reference what is returned.

Comment: That just printed "Row " there was nothing after.

Comment: Try changing ```if (!$result) echo mysql_error();``` to ```echo mysql_error();```. If the echo in my first comment doesn't show anything, there's a problem getting the row.

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, also put the ```echo mysql_error();``` after the fetch.

Comment: There is no error. I can do that query in phpmyadmin and I get a number (what I want) ex. 10. I put it in both places and got no errors.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because you are using mysqli embedded. Try using stored procs

Comment: I'm doing this for a class and this is how we were taught. What do you mean stored procs?

Comment: If the echo .. row didn't print anything other than Row, then the query didn't return anything, and there is a problem with the query. The SQL looks fine, but there's a problem elsewhere in the php code. For instance, you are mixing mysqli and mysql functions.

Comment: Yeah I knew that. So I made a simple mistake. I never put mysqli_select_db ( $con, "....."); Into my file so it never knew what database to use. I also was not getting errors because I was using mysql_error instead of mysqli_error. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never put mysqli_select_db ( $con, "....."); Into my file so it never knew what database to use. I also was not getting errors because I was using mysql_error instead of mysqli_error. Once I selected the default database, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MySQLi AND calling mysql_error(). Should be

```
mysqli_error($con);
```

Now you should see error messages, if there are any.

Comment: Thanks. There are no errors though so it doesn't solve the main problem.

Comment: I made the change but misunderstood what was going on. I figured it out eventually with your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

echo out mysqli_error($conn) instead of mysql_error()