# PDO returns result, but else statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been stuck on this for some time and I don't seem to be able to figure out what the issue is. I am making a very simple, basic sign in page for my project, however I can't seem to get my 'else' statement to work.

When a username and password are entered correctly, I can successfully get the Sign In message to show up, however if I enter username&password incorrectly, I would want to have no results and still show 'Incorrect username or password' message, however it always shows as blank.

PS: I know about sessions and the rest, I just want to get this sorted before I even attempt to work on those.

I looked elsewhere in the past few hours but I was unable to find any help that could help me troubleshoot.

```
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$user_password = $_POST['password'];


if (isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]))  {

    $results = $pdo->query("SELECT user_name, user_password FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' AND  user_password = '" . $user_password . "'");

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        $result = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' AND  user_password = '" . $user_password . "'")->fetchColumn();

        //var_dump($result);

        if ($result > 0){
            echo "Signed In";
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pleas have a read of [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show?

Comment: it shows  `/srv/http/default/public/signin.php:20:string '1' (length=1)`

Comment: when it should be zero?

Comment: No, when the username and password are entered correctly, I can't test what it'd show when entered wrong as it shows blank.

Comment: right, so the issue is not the else statement but your data collection -- the first PDO

Comment: Read the PHP error log, what does it tell you ?

Comment: Unfortunately vagrant does not store any logs so I am unable to check it. I however checked if the query works and it returns everything fine in the database

Comment: I fnd it hard to believe any programming environment does not store logs. If this is indeed true then you need to stop using Vagrant as soon as possible and use something which helps rather than hinders you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's true, it's a University project and we are required to use this, sadly. I have just checked it again in the database and with `->fetchColumn();` the user_name returns as 1, while the user_password returns with 'admin', which is simply the password in this case. I've changed it to `fetch();` and now I get this from var_dump `array (size=2)
  'COUNT(*)' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)` I assume, that also changed the password to '1', however it still doesn't make the else statement work.

Comment: You're incorrect. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+error+logs+on+Vagrant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first PDO is incorrect.

## Passwords should [always be hashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash). Do it.

You need to change to this:

```
 $results = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_name, user_password FROM users 
            WHERE user_name = :user ");
 $results->execute(['user' => $user_name]);
 $found = $results->fetch();
 print_r("found row: ".$found);
```

Please read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash) to improve your SQL handling in PHP.

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907751/select-count-from-table-of-mysql-in-php) (and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100994/3536236)) and also read about exploring [PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel).

As you use Vagrant and erroneously mention, that Vagrant does not give error logs, please [Google this information](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+error+logs+on+Vagrant) to find that Vagrant **DOES** give PHP error logs. You need to use them.

almost every part of your code is NOT best practise and needs to be heavily improved.

---

## Complete fix of your code

*Assuming username is a unique value*

```
if (!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]))  {

    $results = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_name, user_password FROM users 
               WHERE user_name = :user");
    $results->execute([':user' => $_POST["username"] ]);
    $foundRow = $results->fetchAll();

    if(count($foundRow) < 1){  
       // no user found
       echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
    }
    elseif(password_verify($_POST["password"],$foundRow['user_password']) !== true){
       // bad password given
       echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
    }
    else {
       echo "Signed In";   
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin.