# PHP PDO Prepared Statement MySQL Count of Select where X LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Using PHP v. 5.2.14 and PDO-MySQL extension.

I am new to prepared statements.  Need to create a search form (so user input) and a working query of the "Select all X where X like…" variety.

Code and Results:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where title LIKE :search_term';
// Later access as num_books
$prep = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$num = $prep->execute(array(':search_term' => '%'.$search_term. '%'));
$total=$num->fetchColumn();
```

Var dump of $prep:
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(58) "SELECT COUNT(*) from t_books where title LIKE :search_term" }

Fatal error: **Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object**

If $prep is an object, then $num should be an object.  But it is boolean (true).  What happened here?

But more importantly, how can I do a count?

I read [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/count-with-pdo) -.   Suggestions there do not work for me because I need a Prepared Statement.  Will have user input.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) only returns a boolean indicating success or failure, so your variable `$num` is not what you want to fetch from.  By assigning the result to `$num`, you are not assigning the object `$prep`, but rather only the return value of the method call to `execute()` (`TRUE`).

Instead, [`fetchColumn()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) from `$prep`, your PDOStatement object.

```
$num = $prep->execute(array(':search_term' => '%'.$search_term. '%'));
if ($num) {
  $total = $prep->fetchColumn();
}
```

Beyond that, your SQL should execute correctly and the one column it returns should contain the count you need.

In this case (especially since you are calling `fetchColumn()` with no argument) it doesn't matter, but for future readers, it is advisable to name the `COUNT()` aggregate with an alias that can then be used in an associative or object fetch:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_books from t_books where title LIKE :search_term';
// Later access as num_books
```

Comment: It worked.  I am on my way to doing pagination with PDO thanks to you.  Thanks too for the suggestion of the alias. As I learn new things, I like to learn best practices.