# about mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I want get count of rows from my table where X == 7

```
+----+----------+-------+---+   
| id | username | email | X |
+----+----------+-------+---+
|  1 |          |       | 7 |
|  2 |          |       | 7 |
|  3 |          |       | 7 |
|  4 |          |       |   |
|  5 |          |       |   |
+----+----------+-------+---+
```

There are 3 rows where X == 7

**How can i get the number of those rows?**

Comment: select count(*) as total from table where x=7 some thing like this!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM yourtable where x = 7;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9fa6/1)

this will give you one value:

```
| COUNT(ID) |
-------------
|         3 |
```

---

If you want to do that for all the values of x's, add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(id) TheCount
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY x;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b22c/2)

Comment: what is difference between count(*) and count(id)?

Comment: @Akam : `count(*)` count NULL also. Check [**this**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col).

Comment: @Akam - For this query, there isn't, they are the same, but it might differ if there are nullable values coming from the `id`. See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1) for more details.

Comment: that is why I prefer to use `COUNT(1)`

Comment: i dont need there id i need how many row have the same X . and how can i show the number in my table . im sorry

Comment: like if there is 8 rows where X==7 i want show 8 in echo

Comment: @SchyzoPhrény Do you want to display all the rows that had `x = 7`? See my edit please.

Comment: im sorry but you don't understand me i want to calcul how many rows have the same colomn

Comment: @SchyzoPhrény So this for all the values not for a specific value `x = 7` right? and which column should have the same value in? the `x` column?

Comment: i got the answer from Fahim Parkar thank u

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE X = 7"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

From [Count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/883365/1456376)

As a note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: feel free to use that comment without attribute its created by php chat room not alone by me

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular `count` in the SQl query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `yourTable` WHERE `X`=7;
```

Answer (score 1):

if column x is of type `INT` use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableName WHERE X=7
```

if column x is of type `varchar` use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableName WHERE X='7'
```

I believe you have x column as integer...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table_name WHERE x='7'
```

But really, do a google search next time ^^