# Converting mysql_query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to rewrite all my queries to a PDO format.
Currently I am trying to rewrite this function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

mysql_query function

```
    function checkLogin() {

    $this->sQuery = "SELECT * FROM users 
          WHERE gebruikersnaam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersnaam']) . "'
          AND wachtwoord = '" . sha1($_POST['wachtwoord']) . "'";

    $this->rResult = mysql_query($this->sQuery)
            or die("Er is iets misgegaan " . mysql_error());


    if (mysql_num_rows($this->rResult) == 1) {  // login name was found            
        $this->aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->rResult);
        $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = $this->aRow['voornaam'];

        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
}
```

And this is how far I've come with the PDO:

```
       function checkLoginPDO(){
    $connect = new PDO(host, username, password); // Database Connectie maken (De host, username & password zijn in de config.php aan te passen)
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
          WHERE gebruikersnaam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersnaam']) . "'
          AND wachtwoord = '" . sha1($_POST['wachtwoord']) . "'"; 
    $value = $connect->prepare($sql); //Een variabele aanmaken die de PDO vast houdt. Vervolgens word de code voorbereid door de prepare functie
    $value->execute(); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($value->fetch()) == 1){
        $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = $row['voornaam'];
        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong/forgetting?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` should have been removed during your conversion process.

Comment: I removed the real_escape_string function but the after loggin in, i still get a blank screen!

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: Matter of fact I've just noticed more mysql_* functions. If you are converting to PDO then you shouldn't be seeing any mysql_*. Also, if you've made changes to your actual code, please update it here so you don't get any repeat answers.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in C:\wamp\www\pvb\resources\functions.php on line 44
( ! ) PDOException: invalid data source name in C:\wamp\www\pvb\resources\functions.php on line 44

Which is:
$connect = new PDO(host, username, password);

Strange.. because those are correctly defined.

Comment: Read the manual, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: (because you're a dutch man, you can read [this great tut](http://phptuts.nl/view/27/) too...)

Comment: I found it, thank god!  my defined 'host' value was 'localhost'.  It had to be mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname ofcourse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
function checkLoginPDO(){
    $connect = new PDO(host, username, password); // Database Connectie maken (De host, username & password zijn in de config.php aan te passen)
    // define sql query string with special placeholders in the form of ?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE gebruikersnaam=?
      AND wachtwoord =?";
    // prepare statement based on sql query string
    $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
    // bind first question mark with value from $_POST, first question mark will be replaced with that value
    $statement->bindParam(1, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
    // do the same for second question mark
    $statement->bindParam(2, sha1($_POST['wachtwoord']));
    // execute this prepared statement with binded values
    $statement->execute();
    // fetch row from the result in the form of associated array
    if(($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = $row['voornaam'];
        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
    // free statement memory
    $statement = null;
}
```

Note: Code is not tested.

When working with PDO you should be using its way of dealing with queries and database. Using any of mysql_* functions is not an optimal way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, determine which type of error handling you want. PDO defaults to `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` which means that you don't get any errors. I recommend you to use `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` which means that you need to work with `try { ... } catch() { ... }` blocks around your code.
- Secondly, when you are using PDO, you can't use `mysql_*` functions. So using `mysql_real_escape_string` is not correct. Furthermore, because you are using prepared statements you don't need any SQL injection protection at all. But you need to use [param binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).
- You also have some `mysql_query` around line 7...
- PDO does not have a build in `mysql_num_rows` function. You should put a `COUNT(*)` statement in your query for that. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/883382/1149495)

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkLoginPDO(){
$connect = new PDO(host, username, password); // Database Connectie maken (De host, username & password zijn in de config.php aan te passen)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE gebruikersnaam=:gebruikersnaam
      AND wachtwoord = :wachtwoord"; 
$value = $connect->prepare($sql);
$value->bind(':gebruikersnaam',$_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
$value->bind(':wachtwoord',sha1($_POST['wachtwoord']));
$value->execute();
$data = $value->fetchAll();
if(count($data) > 0){
    $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = $data[0]['voornaam'];
    header("location: dashboard.php");
}
```

}