# make this code PDO friendly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've just started using PDO instead of the mysql functions. But now I'm stuck on a part of my php blog.

How would I make this code a little more PDO friendly:

```
$total_results = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as num   
    FROM php_blog"));
$total_pages = ceil($total_results['num'] / $blog_postnumber);
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
   if ($page == $i) {
      echo "<span class='current'>$i</span>";
   }
   else {
      echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=$i\">$i</a>";
   }
}
```

I tried with PDO rowCount(), but it doesn't seem to work...

Sorry for my poor english, I'm from Sweden!

Comment: yo don't need `rowCount()`, you need `fetchColumn()`. What exactly have you tried anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->exec( "select count(*) as num from php_blog" );
$results = $stmt->fetch();
$total_results = $results[ 'num' ];
$total_pages = ceil( $total_results / $blog_postnumber );
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
   if ($page == $i) {
      echo "<span class='current'>$i</span>";
   }
   else {
   echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=$i\">$i</a>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that code displays the blog navigation, but I get an error to,
"Warning: Illegal string offset 'num' in C:\wamp\www\meranhem\blogg.php on line 70". And line 70 is this line: "$total_results = $results[ 'num' ];"

Comment: try 'select count(*) num...' instead.. also - what's the output of 'print_r( $results, true );' ?

Comment: If its to a web page - use 'view source'

Answer (score 0):

rowCount doesn't work with mySQL in PDO. Instead, you just run the count(*) query.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE foo = bar"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Source: [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/count-with-pdo)

Comment: why this answer, based on other [wrong] answer, was ever upvoted?