# PHP - Return count(*) results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can I return the *number of counted rows* with PDO?

This is my code:

```
$n=$dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users_notifications WHERE userid=0 OR userid=:userid");
$n->bindParam(":userid",$userdata['id']);
$n->execute();
$notifications = count($n);
```

This returns just 1. Although there are **2** results when I run the query in the database: `SELECT count(*) FROM users_notifications WHERE userid=0 OR userid=:userid`

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count` SQL function is an aggregate function that returns **one row** with the number of rows matching the `where` clause.

PHP's `count` returns the number of rows in a result set, which, as illustrated in the previous paragraph, should be one. Instead, you should retrieve the value of the result **column**. E.g.:

```
$n=$dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) as c FROM users_notifications WHERE userid=0 OR userid=:userid");
$n->bindParam(":userid",$userdata['id']);
$n->execute();
$result = $n->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$notifications = $result['c'];
```