# MySQL rows count with PHP and show result

Tags: php, mysql, database, count, rows

I want to make an API that when you access it it will show result in text format of how many rows are on my database.

Database info:

```
Username: predator_db

DB Name: predator_db

Table Name: database
```

I tried a couple of codes and I could not get it to work.

Code tried:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","predator_db","PASS");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("predator_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM database");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Response Of Code: "Total Rows: " < Does not show how many rows. Error Log:

```
[05-Feb-2015 23:44:58 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/predator/public_html/api/resolver/number.php on line 2
[05-Feb-2015 23:44:58 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/predator/public_html/api/resolver/number.php on line 10
```

Comment: so, just start show us your try code :-)

Comment: so just change `select count(*) FROM database`

Comment: Did that, Still does same thing, does not say how many rows. @KimAlexander

Comment: but what is there? what do you see?

Comment: try `mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH);`  and tell me more about outputs you see

Comment: Tried it, Nothing @KimAlexander I just edited with the errors I got when I used the code On My Question maybe that will help.

Comment: so mysql is deprecated that is true, you should use msqli  or PDO then

Comment: PDO does not work with mysql that good, I tried that.

Comment: what???? PDO works fine with any db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo/883382#883382 Not according to this.

Comment: that link you've sent is about imaginated situation, in most cases, and in your particular case pdo will return number of rows

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fetch the results from `database`... not from your actual database of `predator_db`.

I'll do it with the basics, but please look into MySQLi prepared statements and/or PDO.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "predator_db", "PASS", "predator_db");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select COUNT(id) AS count FROM `database`");
// make sure it worked
if(!$result) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // echo it
    echo "Rows: " . $num_rows['count'];
}
```

Comment: The question says the table name is `database`

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS count FROM predator_db' at line 1

Comment: Fixed First Error, Then second error: Error: Table 'predator_db.predator_db' doesn't exist

Comment: Apologies, try the amended fix. @Predator

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not a good idea to name a table after a reserved keyword like `database`. However, if you are going to go that route, you will always have to place the name in backticks ``. So, your query should be

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM `database`");
```

Also, look into MYSQLi, as the old MySQL driver is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS", "DB_NAME");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select COUNT(*) AS count FROM DB_NAME.DB_TABLE");
if(!$result) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "Rows: " . $num_rows['count'];
}
?>
```