# Allow a maximum of three rows in the table during insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can i limit inserts to just 3 rows for each category in table? I am working with php and pdo. I have some categories and each category must have max 3 subcategories. Everything is stored in db, tables look like this.

To make it clear! I have some categories in menu and each of those category can have maximum of 3 subcategories. Of course not with the same name, but it can't be more then 3 in each category. I have input for one at the time, that means you can insert more then one at the time, but it can't be more then 3 in db.

**Some category**

```
 - some subcategory
 - some subcategory
 - some subcategory
```

**category**

id | category |

**subcategory**

id | subcategory_name | id_category |

For now, my code looks like this.

```
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $InputSubcategory = $_POST['InputSubcategory'];
    $InputId          = $_POST['InputId'];

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subcategory(subcategory_name,id_category) 
                          VALUES(:field1,:field2)");
    $sql->execute(array(':field1' => $InputSubcategory,
                        ':field2' => $InputId));
    $affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows > 0) {
    header( "refresh:0" );
    die();
    }
}         
if(isset($_POST['cat'])) {

    $InputCategory = $_POST['InputCategory'];

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO category(category) 
                          VALUES(:field1)");
    $sql->execute(array(':field1' => $InputCategory));
    $affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows > 0) {
    header( "refresh:0" );
    die();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I made it work! What i did is next. `Count()` rows in each table, then in if compare whether the counted number greater than or equal to 3. If `if` is true show error if false continue to insert.

```
    if(isset($_POST['cat'])) {

    $nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from category')->fetchColumn();  

    if ($nRows >= 3) {
      echo'
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>Warning</strong>
          <hr class="message-inner-separator">
          <p>You reach maximum category limit.</p>
      </div>';
      header( "refresh:2;url=insert.php" );
    } else {

      $InputCategory = $_POST['InputCategory'];

      $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO category(category) 
                            VALUES(:field1)");
      $sql->execute(array(':field1' => $InputCategory));
      $affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
      if ($affected_rows > 0) {
      header( "refresh:0" );
      die();
      }  

    }
}
```

Comment: apply `LIMIT 3` in your both insert query. thanks.

Comment: One solution is to add an insert trigger to the `category` table to prevent the insert.  What do you want to happen when an attempt is made to insert a fourth subcategory?

Comment: Nothing special, just to say that maximum number of subcategories are inserted. If i LIMIT 3 that means that i cant insert more then 3 at once or that 3 is maximum of rows in table?

Comment: then you need to take care of that at the input level, not as the SQL level. ^ that's what I got from that comment

Comment: As you can see in m code, i have rowCount() at the end of insert query..can i use it? But, user can only insert one row at the time..will it work?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean if there is the same sub-category names? you need to give us an example and put it in your question please, and not in comments so everyone will see it.

Comment: then query select first, count if there 3 already in db. if not, continue with insert. This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/883365/ might help and `if($stmt->rowCount() >= 3)` might work too. Use PHP's `count()` function too http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: thank you, can you maybe implement that to my code above?

Comment: It's funny. This question never came up before. It's come up 3 or 4 times now in as many weeks!

Comment: What if someone enters a row in between your SELECT and your INSERT!

Comment: Your solution isn't proper, you're vulnerable to concurrency, just like @Strawberry wrote. If you have max 3 something per something, a much saner option is to just always insert without caring for the item amount and always display last 3 items. That way you still prevented people from having more than 3 something per something, and you are not going to experience any issues due to concurrent access.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent more than 3 from being inserted into the database itself, with a trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER subcategory_bi BEFORE INSERT ON subcategory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subcategory sc WHERE sc.category_id = NEW.category_id) >= 3 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'this category already has the max allowed subcategories';
  END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```