# PHP PDO:Login System

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a PHP PDO Login system but i keep getting an error, perhaps some       part of my code is incorrect.

```
//LOG IN VERIFICATION
if (isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['pass'])) {
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=" . host . ";dbname=" . database, user, auth);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if (!empty($_POST['username'])&& !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
            //username and password sent from Form
            $usernames = trim($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['pass'];
            $select= $con -> prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
            $select ->execute();
            $results = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])) {
               header('location:home.php');
            } else{
                header('location:login.php');
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I suspect the error to be here

```
$select= $con -> prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$select ->execute();
$results = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

because i verified the connection to the database. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error you got while execute your code???

Comment: I keep heading to the login page even if the entry is not in database.

Comment: your code failed then and you need to find out why; debug. You have an obvious typo. checking for errors would have told you that.

Comment: plus, since you're PDO, you should be using prepared statements. You'll get hit by a serious SQL injection

Comment: Thanks for the help and vote.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to `$usernames`, not `$username`. However, the real problem is `count($results)` - you cannot count the rows this way. Which means, the count will be 0, hence the `else` branch is executed. See here: [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo/883523#883523).

Edit: In such cases, simply debug your code and `var_dump(count($results))`, for example. You have a simple `if` statement - if an unexpected branch is executed, something is wrong with the `if` condition.