# PDO rowCount only returning one

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a SELECT query, like this:

```
$stmnt = $conn->prepare("SELECT post_title, posts_cat FROM posts WHERE posts_cat=:posts_cat");
$stmnt->execute(array(':posts_cat' => $cat_id));
$post_info = $stmnt->fetch();
$count = $stmnt->rowCount();
```

If there are no posts it shows none, but if there's one or more then it displays only one.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: Use PDO's `fetchAll()` function to fetch all the rows into an array

Comment: Example 2 in http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last **DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

**[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)** is not for a `SELECT` query, use a separate `COUNT` query for that or fetch all rows in an array and `count` its size

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it correct to use SELECT COUNT with fetchColumn?

Comment: Yes it is fine to do so

Comment: Ok great thank you so much. I'm just migrating from MySQLi to PDO.

Comment: that nasty rumor *again*

Comment: You might want to quash it then because this thesis doesn't. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16776839/1570534

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use `rowCount()` with select query
use a different query with `count()` for counting rows

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE posts_cat = :posts_cat"; 
$stmnt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmnt->execute(array(':posts_cat' => $cat_id)); 
$count = $stmnt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Wrong answer and absolutely wrong up-votes.

Comment: @Rajesh Patel thank you so much. I have one question whiteout using `$stmnt->fetchAll();` cant you directly use `$stmnt->rowCount();` like in mysqli `num_rows`?

Comment: thanks @HankyPanky, it was not known to me many thanks

Comment: You're most welcome! If you edit the answer to reflect that I will be able to take away my down-vote. Currently i cant since its locked

Answer (score 0):

*Of course* you are getting the right number of rows returned. 1 means that only one row was found. If you want more rows to be found, add more rows to your database to match the condition.

Whether you need such a function at all - is another question, already answered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776839/285587)