# PHP : not able to return sql count value

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in PHP programming. Here is my code :

```
class AdminActions extends DBManager{
    public function loginUser($username, $password){
        $dbh = $this->getConnection();
        $smt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(1) FROM admin WHERE admin_name=:username AND admin_password=:password"); 
        $smt->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $smt->bindValue(':password', $password);
        $count = $smt->fetchColumn();
        return $count;
    }
}
```

I am not able to return the  value of $count. There is no error to be displayed (no output). I would like to have answers containing the function `fetchColumn()` . Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the error are you getting ?

Comment: @AhmedGinani I am getting no error .Its just blank.

Comment: $smt->execute(); missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to exec the request and to select what column you wanna count. Try :

```
class AdminActions extends DBManager{
public function loginUser($username, $password){
    $dbh = $this->getConnection();
    $smt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM admin WHERE admin_name=:username AND admin_password=:password"); 
    $smt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $smt->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $smt->execute();
    return $smt->fetchColumn();
}
```

From : [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

Comment: Oh wait its giving me this error now: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean`

Comment: I edit my code, execute() is alone now. Try this new

Comment: Okay looks like return doesnt print the value, echo does. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per document you have to execute pdo statement. you have to execute your query.

```
$smt->execute();
```