# unable to get to count

Tags: php, html, count

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_u) FROM account");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = $result['count(id_u)'];
        echo $count;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get it to count the amount of registered users we have by counting the amount of `id_u`'s (user id).

Like I said in the comments, It might be similar to other posts but those don't explain how to fix my situation since they are not quite the same.

Comment: you forget to close the count -->$result['count(id_u)'];

Comment: You have a litle syntax error here: $count = $result['count(id_u']; the closing parenthesis is missing

Comment: ok I fixed that, but now it still doesnt echo anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

Comment: @Script47 it might be similar but it doesn't explain how to fix my situation because it's a bit different

Comment: [Select the number of rows using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/count)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

After testing the issue you are experiencing; I managed to solve why your solution is not working. It appears that it is due to you calling `COUNT(id_u)` in the SQL query, then in the `echo` statement you are trying to get `count(id_u)` which doesn't exist in the array. Try

```
$count = $result;
$count = $result['COUNT(id_u)'];
```

---

To detect where the issue is stemming from I'd suggest you add in a `print_r($result);`. This will give you an idea what is returning from your SQL query in an array format. Once you see what data is returned and available, you can then determine how you echo/print the result.

**My opinion on how this should be done:**

The use of prepared statements in this is not necessary in my opinion for counting rows.

What I would do is:

```
$rowCount = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $rowCount;
```

Comment: Hmm I put the `print_r($result);` but in stead of printing it, it just showed nothing. And for the second piece of code you put. I replace everything i had with that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Arjen Try what I just posted above. I tested it locally and it appears to work for me.

Comment: Also @Arjen the reason you are just getting nothing/white screen is because your errors are turned off. I'd advise to turn your errors on whilst developing to see where the issues are coming from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/5030092

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($result['id_u']);
```