# Get count of Mysql rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In the below code when I `var_dump($result)` I can see the data I want is in there... but I have yet to be able to get to it.

Code:

```
try {   
    $query = new dbquery(Connection::make($dbconfig['dbinfo']));
    $count = $query->runSQL("select count(*) from table_name");

    $result = $count->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
    echo $result[0];
    echo $result[1];
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

SQL:

```
public function runSQL($sql, $params = NULL) {
    //Prepares the SQL Statement you pass through
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Binds the Parameters I pass through on execute, so no need for seperate $statement->bindParam()
    $statement->execute($params);

    //Returns the statement.
    return $statement; 
}
```

output of var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["count(*)"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" } } Array
```

it's the `["count(*)]` key I need, the value `3`

I've tried the below and none gives me the right value:

```
echo $result[0];
echo $result[1];
echo $result['count(*)'];
```

Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong, all i want to know is the number of rows.

Comment: you have to add an alias to your `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting array inside an array as result. You can do the following:

```
echo $result[0][0];
```

OR

```
echo $result[0]['count(*)'];
```

**Note** that it is a good habit to do [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) in the query, for better readability. For eg, `COUNT(*)` can be aliased as `total_count`:

```
$count = $query->runSQL("select count(*) AS total_count from table_name");
```

Now, you can access the total row count as follows:

```
echo $result[0]['total_count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid use of fetchAll in cases that only returns 1 row (COUNT, SUM or any group functions)

You can use

```
echo $result[0][0];
```

Or

```
$result = $count->fetchOne(); #or $count->fetch(); read the docs to the right method
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL command to get the number of rows is

```
select count(*) as alias from table_name
```