# SELECT COUNT(*) returns an object instead of an integer

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, count

I have a database table `timestamps_sessions` containing timestamps of when a user begins an exercise on my webpage, and which is only updated when the user actually finishes it. Therefore, every row always has a value in the `started` column, but not always in the `finished` column. The latter is `NULL` by default.

My `SELECT COUNT()` statement works perfectly when I query it in Sequel Pro, and returns the correct integer of 11. That is to say: there are indeed only eleven rows that have values in both `started` and `finished`.

Yet when I execute it in PHP, it returns an object containing

```
{
    current_field: null,
    field_count: null,
    lengths: null,
    num_rows: null,
    type: null
}
```

The statement I successfully query in Sequel Pro is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(finished) FROM timestamps_sessions
```

The statement I unsuccessfully use in PHP is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(finished) FROM timestamps_sessions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$exercise['clears'] = $result;
```

There are several other `SELECT` queries being performed to the same database and same table without issue. It's only the `COUNT()` statement that seems to be malfunctioning.

What am I doing wrongly, and how should I do it instead?

My goal is to count the number of rows with a non-empty `finished` column, without passing on the actual data in order to preserve bandwidth. All I need is the integer.

Comment: What is `$conn`?

Comment: Use an alias like `total` in the the SELECT clause and access the first row's `['total']` element.

Comment: If `$conn` is a PDO object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo

Comment: @MartinHeralecký It's a MySQLi object, as you can see from the properties in the object provided in the question - `num_rows` is a MySQLi result property.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `$result` is an object as expected. It's the result returned by the `mysqli::query()` method. Before you can access the data from this query, you need to fetch it. It will be easier if you give an alias to the count, as it will become easier to access the count.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(finished) as cnt FROM timestamps_sessions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$exercise['clears'] = $row['cnt'];
```

- [`mysqli::query()` docs](http://php.net/mysqli.query)
- [`mysqli::fetch_assoc()` docs](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch_assoc)

Answer (score 1):

you have missing code `mysql_fetch_array` in order to fetch first record

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(finished) totals FROM timestamps_sessions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$total = $row['totals'];
```

Comment: You cannot mix MySQL and MySQLi libraries.

Comment: yes I fixed it sorry

Comment: Also, when using the object oriented interface, `fetch_assoc()` is a method called on the object without any parameters. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to the count function can be anything, since you just want the number of rows, not their data.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM timestamps_sessions WHERE finished IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(finished) AS count_finished FROM timestamps_sessions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $exercise['clears'] = $row['count_finished'];
```

Give the count an alias like count_finished. Then from the result object you need to fetch the row. The row has your data in it.

Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp