# Query does not return a result

Tags: php, pdo

I converted a web-based application from MySQLi to PDO, because I want to use Microsoft SQL-Server as database too. PDO works like a charm with MySQL database. Now I tried it for the first time with MS-SQL and it does not. Almost every query has to be updated. It is very frustrating.

The simple code below drives me nuts:

```
$ComputerGUID = "5BEC3779-B002-46BA-97C4-19158C13001F";

$SqlSelectQuery = "SELECT computermapping.PrinterGUID, 
                case when computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end AS isDefaultPrinter
                FROM computermapping 
                LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter ON computerdefaultprinter.ComputerGUID = computermapping.ComputerGUID 
                AND computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID = computermapping.PrinterGUID
                WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = :ComputerGUID";
$SqlStatement  = $pdo->prepare( $SqlSelectQuery );
$SqlStatement -> bindValue( ":ComputerGUID", $ComputerGUID, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$SqlStatement->execute();

$SelectQueryNumRows = $SqlStatement->rowCount();
IF ( $SelectQueryNumRows > 0 ) {

    $Data = $SqlStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} ELSE {
    echo "The query did not return a result ...";
}
```

It is working fine with MySQL and returns me a result.

With Microsoft SQL-Server it get **NO RESULT**. (The query did not return a result ...)

Running the same query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is working fine too:

[image: Result in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio]

Monitoring the query when running the code with SQL Server Profiler shows the following:

[image: Monitoring with Microsoft SQL Server Profiler]

Comment: would you please `var_dump($Data);` or `print_r($Data);` what do you see ?

Comment: Follow the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-description) which says "some databases __may__ return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is __not guaranteed__ for all databases and __should not be relied on__ for portable applications"

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I remove the IF-block with the row-count, I have access to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-description) mentions:

> some databases **may** return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour **is not guaranteed** for all databases and **should not be relied** on for portable applications.

So, you should not use `rowCount`. But as you fetch all data - use it:

```php
$SqlStatement->execute();

$Data = $SqlStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// in case of no data - empty array will be returned

if ($Data) {
    // process $Data;
} else {
    echo "The query did not return a result ...";
}
```

Also note that `$Data` can be `false` in case of errors and if required you should process this value of `$Data`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of this. I use the row-count clause extensively in my code and I will have to do a lot of changes :-(

Comment: @Walhalla but now if you think of it, it just makes no sense to use rowCount if you have the data itself anyway. Less work, more compatible code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense : As we found the root-cause here, I did some reading. (e.g. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)) This IF-clause in my code is a relict from the past, as it was `mysql_num_rows` before. Using this seems to extra query the database a second time to get the row-count. Very bad. I will convert my code.

Answer (score 0):

For most drivers, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. But if you are using PHP Driver for SQL Server, as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), *if the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, a PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY cursor returns -1* and a *PDO::CURSOR_SCROLLABLE cursor returns the number of rows in the result set*.

You need to prepare the statement like this:

```
$SqlStatement  = $pdo->prepare(
   $SqlSelectQuery, 
   array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)
);
```

Comment: I had a closer look on your answer now and tested it by adding the mentioned "PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL".
Is it true, that "rowCount()" will work now? What will happen, if I would use it with MySQL too? Thx

Comment: @Walhalla If you use PHP Driver for SQL Server (pdo_sqlsrv), as is mentioned in the documentation, the answer is yes. I'm not able to test this against MySQL database, but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo) gives additional explanations about `PDO::rowCount()` capabilities..