# How to get mysql_num_rows with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mysql-num-rows

How can I easily get the number of rows returned with "`SELECT *`" SQL-query?

```
function valid_credentials($db,$name,$pw) {
    try {

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ib_members WHERE name=:val AND pw=:val2");
    $sth->bindValue(":val",$name);
    $sth->bindValue(":val2",$pw);   
    $sth->execute();


    $numrows = $sth->fetchColumn();

    return $numrows;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

That returns 14, which is definately not the number of rows returned, but it's the ID that  the first row has.

Comment: $sth->rowCount();

[http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

just check the example, this question can be found by googling in couple of seconds, not sure why bother to ask!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of rows in SELECT query with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo)

Comment: Hmm. It turns out that `mysql_num_rows()` only worked for SELECT statements because internally `mysql_query()` buffered all of the rows returned in order to derive this information. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/770045/862594) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` statements, use [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

For `SELECT` statements, count the rows manually in your `while( $sth->fetch() )` loop (you can `break` out of the loop if the count exceeds a certain threshold, for instance), or execute a separate query to have the database return the row count (for example, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column = ?`).