# mySQL SELECT PDOStatement->rowCount

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, rowcount

I am just wondering what the definitive answer to this question is. The PHP PDO documentation warns that `PDOStatement->rowCount` cannot be relied up to return the number of rows "affected" with a `SELECT` statement.  And yet I find that this continues to work perefectly with mySQL + PHP version after version. Perhaps there is an issue when using another DB but if I don't ever want to migrate to another DB should I really care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should still care about the usage of that method. It's not just the database, [but PHP itself can be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769767/pdos-rowcount-not-working-on-php-5-2-6).

If you want to play it safe, it's better if you just issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! SELECT COUNT it is then!

Comment: I'm not sure running a query twice and assuming the same results were returned each time is safe exactly.