# PDO looping through and printing fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, fetchall

I'm having trouble getting my data from fetchAll to print selectively.

In normal mysql I do it this way:

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
   $id = $row['id'];
   $n = $row['n'];
   $k = $row['k'];
}
```

In PDO, I'm having trouble. I bound the params, then I'm saving the fetched data into $rs like above, with the purpose of looping through it the same way..

```
$sth->execute();
$rs = $query->fetchAll();
```

Now comes the trouble part. What do I do PDO-wise to get something matching the while loop above?! I know I can use print_r() or dump_var, but that's not what I want. I need to do what I used to be able to do with regular mysql, like grabbing $id, $n, $k individually as needed. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It should be

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $n = $row['n'];
  $k = $row['k'];
}
```

If you insist on `fetchAll`, then

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $row) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $n = $row['n'];
   $k = $row['k'];
}
```

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetches only column names and omits the numeric index.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I went with 2, because I have to count it too before looping. So makes more sense to store it in $results before.

Comment: $query->rowCount() _might_ return the count.

Comment: It won't for SELECT statements. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460010/work-around-for-php5s-pdo-rowcount-mysql-issue/660032#660032

Comment: You have an extra right parentheses in this line:

`$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: The while loop does not show anything, at least it does not break the process either. The foreach loop shows the results (I use a dummy query `SHOW TABLES` which should not be the problem). I am fine with the foreach solution, just wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to iterate over the result set in the same function/method or layer where the query was executed, then it is recommend to simply iterate the result object directly instead of calling `fetchAll()`.  (This puts less demand on resources and enjoys a simpler syntax.)  An exception to always avoiding passing `fetchAll()`'s data to a foreach is when you are using one of PDO' specialized payload mutating modes/flags (e.g. `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`).

Pass your result set object as the input of `foreach()`. The foreach will treat the payload as an indexed array of associative arrays and will not complain if there are zero results.

A few demonstrations assuming `$sql = "SELECT id, n, k FROM my_table";` ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/Z4))

```php
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    vprintf("id: %d, n: %s, k: %s\n", $row);
}
```

---

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "id: {$row['id']}, n: {$row['n']}, k: {$row['k']}\n";
}
```

---

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as ['id' => $id, 'n' => $n, 'k' => $k]) {
    echo "id: $id, n: $n, k: $k\n";
}
```

---

```
$result = [];
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as ['id' => $id, 'n' => $n, 'k' => $result[$id][$n]]);
var_export($result);
```

Notice that none of the above techniques need to call PDO's `fetch()` method to access the equivalent data produced by `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

The exact same technique can be used for the result object produced by executing a prepared statement with PDO.  Just pass the object in and don't bother manually calling `fetch()`.

Comment: I sincerely beg my pardon for the tone. After all the time l still cannot hold it. But honestly, here we go again: a fair desire to share the knowledge, but completely misplaced. The only PDO related example should be just a foreach over $stmt, probably to fill the resulting array while augmenting the data. Other examples should go somewhere else, where foreach being the main topic. The demand to "grab $id, $n, $k individually" makes this question too localized and unfit with the generalized title. How to loop over results is one question. How to get your variables is completely different.