# PDO - get two select values into an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

I have this PDO:

```
$id = 1;
$title = 'resourceName';
$url = 'resourceURL';
$result = array($title => $url);

include('../dbconnect.php');

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT resourceName, resourceURL FROM Resources WHERE categoryID = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute(array_values($result));
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($row);
```

I am just getting this error: 
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

How can make the PDO result be an array where resourceName is the key and resourceURL is the value?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519872/pdo-looping-throug-and-printing-fetchall

Answer (score 1):

You are binding unneeded parameters to the query.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute(array_values($result)); //On this line. These parameters are 
                                         not needed
```

Let me explain

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

Binds the value of $id to the SQL Parameter `:id` and Again

```
$stmt->execute(array_values($result));
```

You are binding another parameters without any indexes.

Thus your query wants 1 parameter and **you are sending two paramters**.

**Solution:** Use one of them

Either

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

Or , directly like this

```
$stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id));
```

After, that get columns from the rows and convert them into a new array in your required format

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
//Now assuming only one was returned from the database this might work
$new = array($row[0] -> resourceName => $row[0] -> resourceURL);
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how do I get the values for resourceName and resourceURL into an array where the former is the key for the latter? The results that are being printed are just a bunch of multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Thank you! What if more than one row is returned? I ask because I need to stick all these values into an unordered list with links

Comment: @NojoRu, Check the result that is being printed and construct your type of array with a foreach() loop.

Comment: why are resourceName and resourceURL in the new array not in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the parameter binding

```
$id = 1;
$title = 'resourceName';
$url = 'resourceURL';
$result = array($title => $url);

include('../dbconnect.php');

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT resourceName, resourceURL FROM Resources WHERE categoryID = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute(); //the array you put in execute will be used as parameter
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($row);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php