# Display SQL Query Result in a HTML Webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm comfortable with PHP/SQL, however my experience with HTML and web development in general is limited.

I need to display the results of a SQL query in a simple HTML webpage. I understand this can be done by embedding some PHP code in the HTML document, using `<?php.......?>`

However my current PHP code contains sensitive login details for my database, and obviously this couldn't be included...

What's the best approach to doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display SQL query results in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300582/display-sql-query-results-in-php) Your question might already be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the appache server pre-processes you .php file, parsing the php code and replacing it by what it should return, so if you do not echo sensitive details, you will don't have problems :)

There is an image will maybe help you to understand : [How it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhu2s.gif)

Well, now you have to understand that Appache will never return itslef the content of the php of your webpage, if it's well configurated, and if you didn't let exploits like free url including (see in php.ini : allow url include or something like that ;) )

I'm talking about apache, but there is other web servers, nginx etc ...

For the displaying of your results, i suggest you print_r() or var_dump().

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mvc framework, like yii or codeigniter.. so you don't need to insert that data in the view files, u just have that in configuration files, which is in another folder..

hope it helps