# Alternative for mysql_num_rows using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Right now I have a PHP file that does a MYSQL query and then counts rows like this:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($count == 1) {
    $message = array('status' => 'ok');
} else {
    $message = array('status' => 'error');
}
```

This works fine but I'm trying to change all my PHP files to use PDO. So how can this be done with PDO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows

Comment: You don't need such a function at all. See [getting row count with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$res = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
$num_rows = $res->fetchColumn();
```

or

```
$res = $DB->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
$res->execute();
$num_rows = $res->fetchColumn();
```

You can use this to ask if data exists or is selected, too:

```
$res = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
$data_exists = ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;
```

Or with your variables:

```
$res = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
$message = ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) ? array('status' => 'ok') : array('status' => 'error');
```

Comment: am i wrong or You will get only  "first column of the next row" http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: Without a parameter in fetchColumn you will get the first column of the selected row. But we only get 1 result and that's the count. The next row means, when you didn't have fetched a row or column, you will begin with the first row of results. After you call fetchColumn again, you will get the content of the next row.

Comment: Yes, fetchcolumn() returns the first colmn of the row, rather, you need to use rowCount()

Answer (score 20):

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');  
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();  
echo $row_count.' rows selected';
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php says: _If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, **this behavior is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications**._

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use PDO's "fetchAll" method, which returns an array containing all the SELECT results.
Then use "count" method to count the array's rows.

Ex:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

Comment: This could be expensive on a large dataset if all you need to know is the number of results.

Comment: @QuinnComendant, the `rowCount()` function returns an accurate count only *after* you fetch all the rows anyway.

Comment: @BillKarwin, did you mean `mysql_num_rows()`? PDO's `rowCount()` method "returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement"—not the same thing.

Comment: @QuinnComendant, check the code in ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c, in function `pdo_mysql_fill_stmt_from_result()`. In the MySQL driver at least, PDOStatement::rowCount() works for both affected rows and result-set rows.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using prepared statements then try:

```
$find = $dbh->query('SELECT count(*) from table');
if ($find->fetchColumn() > 0){
    echo 'found';
}
```

However, if you choose prepared statements, which i highly recommend, then:

```
$find = $dbh->prepare('SELECT count(*) from table');
$find->execute();
if ($find->fetchColumn() > 0){
    echo 'found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be like that...

```
$numRows = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable")->fetchColumn();
echo $numRows;
```