# How do I properly determine if an array that is returned is false?

Tags: php, authentication

I am attempting to build a password-protected area on my site.  However, in my `if` statement, I'm having trouble determining if the array is empty or not.  When the code is run, regardless of what is put into the user/pass fields, it's always testing as true.  For reference, the database being accessed only has 1 row, containing 1 user/pass combo.

```
function verify(){

  $dbhost = "host";
  $dbname = "db";
  $dbuser = "user";
  $dbpass = "password";


  if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))return true;

  $user_name = $_POST["user_name"]; 
  $password = $_POST["password"];

  if ($user_name && $password){ 

    try{ 
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $pe){
      die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = ':user_name' AND password = ':password'";     

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if(!$q){
      die("Execute query error, because: ". $conn->errorInfo());
    }; 

    $q->execute(array(':user_name'=>$user_name, ':password'=>$password));  

    $result = $q->fetchALL();

    if ($result['user_name']=$user_name){ 
      $valid_user = $user_name;
      $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $valid_user;
      return true;
    }
    else{  
      $text = "User Name and Password did not match";
      write_log_in($text);
    }
  }
  else {  
    $text = "This is a secure server. Please log in.";
    write_log_in($text);
  }
}
```

As a side note, I'm aware that my passwords should be stored in at least an MD5 hash format or something similar.  I just wanted to get it working at all before adding in more stuff.

Comment: `if ($result['user_name']=$user_name){ ` should be `if ($result['user_name']==$user_name){ ` - you're mixing up assignment and comparison operators.

Comment: for info, you can check if a variable is an array with is_array($var) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks for the response, got it fixed now.  --RafH Thanks, will read up on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem

```
if ($result['user_name']=$user_name){
```

it should be

```
if ($result['user_name']==$user_name){
```

But why you don't check if you have a result to determine if the user is correct. Because you pass the user in your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think what you suggested was what I initially tried.  But I was not sure how to check whether the query found results or not.

Answer (score 1):

Missing an equal sign:

```
if ($result['user_name'] == $user_name){ 
// ----------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

`$result['user_name']=$user_name` should be `$result['user_name'] === $user_name`.

Also, don't use MD5. Hash the passwords with a slow hashing function like [`hash_pbkdf2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php), which is expensive to attack.

Comment: The author noted at the bottom of his post that he is aware of this

Comment: @Pankrates: It doesn't hurt to suggest something better than MD5.

Comment: very true, although the focus on a different hashing mechanism did not really transpire from your remark immediately ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will read up on that method when I'm ready to try it.

Answer (score -1):

You could go with : if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) because if there is no reslut, the user with the entered passwd is incorrect

Comment: He's not using mysql_*, though - it's using PDO.

Comment: I was able to find some alternatives using PDO to do the same thing which may prove useful.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305230/alternative-for-mysql-num-rows-using-pdo)