# PHP MySQLI Result num_rows returns null

Tags: php, mysqli

Why would num_rows ever return null?  It should always return a number representing the exact number of rows in the result set.

The following code returns null for num_rows:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/psl-config.php';   // host, user, password, database
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE.';charset=utf8', USER, PASSWORD,
                array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

if ($res = $db->query("select 'Hello world!'")){
    if (is_null($res)){
        echo "Result is null<br>";
    }
    if (is_null($res->num_rows)){
        echo "Num rows is null<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Rows returned: ".$res->num_rows."<br>";
    }
    while ($row = $res->fetch_row){
        echo "Text returned = $row[0]<br>";
    }
    echo "Done";

} else {
    echo "SQL error";
}
```

The resulting page displays "Num_rows is null".

This is so simple, I must be missing something!

- The manual says num_rows always returns an int.
- I use mysqli query, which stores the results by default.  I don't need to use store_result.
- Result is not null.

Comment: for PDO i beleive counting rows i going with $res->rowCount();

Comment: Hello world is table ?

Comment: Yes, you should use `$res->rowCount()` and `$res->fetch()`.

Comment: please refer to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows
use $foundRows = $pdo->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn(); is best alternative options than using $res->rowCount(); IMHO.

Comment: You should not use `$res->rowCount()` on select statements. It is unreliable...I learned this literally yesterday.

Comment: "SELECT 'Hello World!'" is valid SQL - no table needed, simply some text to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PDO and not MySQLi, `num_rows` is not applicable. That being said, in general, I have found `rowCount()` is reliable when it comes to MySQL, however, as it states in the manual you should not rely on the `rowCount()` regarding `SELECT` statements:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

The recommendation is to use a `COUNT()` sql statement instead for greatest reliability across database platforms:

```
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `PDO`. So it should be

```
$res->rowCount()
```

instead of

```
$res->num_rows
```

Comment: It is not reliable for select statements. You need to do a `COUNT(*)` statement/query.

Comment: Dont know might be.. but if it is not reliable then `count()` will do the trick..