# num_rows not working pdo,mysqli, always return 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a interesting problem.

// in pdo with function --> not work

```
function UserIsExist($name)
{
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tarskereso_users WHERE email = '$name' LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 1) return 1;
        else return 0;
}
```

// with MySQLi --> not working

```
function UserIsExist($name)
{
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,email FROM tarskereso_users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) 
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
        $stmt->close();
}
```

// In Register.php

```
 ... other ..
        if(UserIsExist($user) == 1)
            $error_msg = "Is Exist";
        else
        {
            $birthdate = $year.'.'.$month.'.'.$day;
            CreateUser($user,$pass,$birthdate,$sex);
                $error_msg = 'Success';
        }
```

So, with function not working, I try with:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,email FROM tarskereso_users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) 
            ... other ...
        else 
            echo 'isnt exist...';
        $stmt->close();
```

but not working, the num_rows always return 0. And the account in the database successfuly created

Comment: Looks like your query is looking for email but you are passing name to your function. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` of all variables involved, including the database connection variables?

Comment: my connection: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=asdelontest;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pw', 
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION))


var_dump($db); --> object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

var_dump($name); --> string(17) "hdasda@bassda.com"

Comment: I try with only text, I deleted the @ and the dot, and this work... But email = '$email' string is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pdo, num_rows won't work.
you have to use $sql->rowCount() method to get number of records in a table.

```
<?php
    $sql = $con->prepare("<YOUR SQL QUERY HERE>");
    $sql->execute();
    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        echo $sql->rowCount() ." rows found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: In the SQL exist the row, but $sql->rowCount() == 0

Comment: Check once again your SQL query properly.
The query expression must match the attribute selection logic.
if the sql query did not have proper algebraic logic, the query returns 0 rows.

Comment: Or you can use your query having a "count(*)" column which calculates the number of rows fetched depending on your WHERE clause.
The while fetching the data, you can use the PDO statement as
`code`
$numRows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['count'];
echo $numRows;