# Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Tags: php, pdo, authentication, session-cookies

I'm reworking a login form to PDO based with OOP in mind. And I am running into the error given above. So I have two files one is an **login.php** and one is an included file called **functions.inc.php**

The code for the **login.php** is as follows.

```
<?php 

include_once("includes/functions.inc.php");

// get username and password from $_POST
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if a user can login (function)

    if(canilogin($username, $password)){
        session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;



        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else{
        $error = true;
    // if no -> $error tonen
    }

}



?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">



<body class="login">
    <div class="grid container_login">
        <div class="login_grid">

            <form class="form_login" action="" method="post">


                <?php if( isset($error) ): ?>
                <div class="form__error">
                    <p>
                        Sorry, we can't log you in with that email address and password. Can you try again?
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>

                <div>
                    <label for="email">EMAIL</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Lucasdebelder@snapshot.be" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label><br/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Atleast 8 characters" required>
                </div>


                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="btn_login">

                </div>

                <p class="center_align">Or</p>
                <br/>
                <a class="center_align" href="register.php">Register here.</a>

            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the **functions.inc.php** where the error is happening, to be precise it happens at `if($result->num_rows != 1){`.

Also the first few lines were the once that worked before but that is done with real escape string to secure against SQL inject but it's kinda a wacky way to do and I decided to try to rework it to PDO.

```
<?php
function canilogin( $username, $password){

    /* THIS IS THE OLD WAY THAT WORKED/WORKS
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "snapshot"); 
    $query = "select * FROM users WHERE email='".$conn->real_escape_string($username). "'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    */







    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=snapshot', 'root', 'root');

    //$query = "select * FROM users WHERE email='".$conn->real_escape_string($username). "'";
    $statement = $conn->prepare("select * from users where email = :username");
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->execute();

    if($result->num_rows != 1){
        return false;
    }
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
            return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST)){` is an insufficient check.  You shouldn't `execute` twice.  Be sure to convert all functions to pdo.

Comment: Have you tried rowCount() instead of num_rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO - Num Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows)

Comment: @mickmackusa how do I implement this into my code? and which functions do I still need to convert into PDO?

Comment: Please put session_start at the very beginning of your script  (unconditional).  Implement error checking in your canilogin function.  Use the duplicate link, read the php manual regarding pdo, implement my earlier suggestions, and update your question with your new failing attempt.  Post your errors.  This is standard practice for any developer who needs to fix their code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having the issue is that `$result` is not correct. Once `$statement->execute();` is executed it becomes a `PDOStatement` object.

First of all remove `$result = $statement->execute();` and try

```
 if($statement->rowCount() != 1){
   return false;
  }
 $user = $statement->fetch();
        if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
            return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```