# Returning the number of affected rows in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO - Num Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows)

I can't return the number of affected rows in PHP and MySQL :

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `bookmark` WHERE `userid` = :userid AND `hash` = :hash";
    $sql_do = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sql_do->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql_do->bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql_do->execute();
    $number = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
```

returns 0.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460010/work-around-for-php5s-pdo-rowcount-mysql-issue will help you?

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` Description: For a SELECT with a LIMIT clause, the number of rows that would be returned were there no LIMIT clause

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS` is used when a query is ran with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Comment: You seem not to have done any research at all. PHP.net and GOOGLE are you best friends. Only after that ask your questions here :) GL with the above hints...

Answer (score 0):

You  can use it on delete or on update

```
echo 'I have deleted ' . $db->affectedRows() . ' users';
```

or

```
echo mysql_affected_rows();
```